# Is this the first actual death in the Asterix books?

Tags: asterix

*Asterix and the Chieftain's Daughter* is the 38th book in the Asterix series, and the fourth to be written by Jean-Yves Ferri and illustrated by Didier Conrad.

Although *Asterix* is full of peril and Roman-bashing, the possibility of actual fatality always seems remote to these stories.

However, in this book a villain exits the story at sea... pursued by a shark's fin! The inference of a deadly conclusion is clear.

Is this the first actual death in the Asterix books?

[image]

Comment: One would argue that being smashed by Obelix obelisk is pretty deadly, but...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In *Asterix in Switzerland*, there are at least two *implied* future deaths (quoting from [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/AsterixInSwitzerland)):

> Back in the Gaulish village, Varius Flavus arrives to pretend to be upset about Asterix and Obelix not getting back and the Gauls having to kill their hostage — at which point a fully-cured (and magic potion-strengthened) Sinusitus emerges from Getafix's hut and punches Flavus into the sky, telling him that, when he lands, he'll be thrown to the lions along with Curius Odus.

As with the shark above, these deaths happen offscreen and indeed may not happen.

In *[Asterix and the Cauldron](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/AsterixAndTheCauldron)*, Asterix and Obelix tries various ways to earn money, including working in the theater - only to get their entire troupe arrested when Obelix shouts "These Romans are crazy!" in the presence of a high ranking official. A&O easily escape and want to spring the leader of the troupe, but he is ecstatic about being able to perform in front of a huge crowd, with lions, even, and refuses. It is implied that he will be be killed by the lions, but, again, this isn't shown.

Comment: Yes. You've also reminded me of *Asterix and the Black Gold* where M Devius Surreptitious and Dubbelosix are seen in the circus ring, receiving an ironic punishment from Caesar.

Comment: In Asterix in Switzerland there also was a roman guy who was thrown into a lake due to a failed party game at a foundee orgy... and he would certainly make into this answer if not for A&O saving him accidentally!

Comment: To point: in Asterix and the Normans (#9) there were cups made of skulls - this indicates that original owners had died, probably violently, in the past. In The Mansion of the Gods (#17) there is a scene in circus with a suspiciously lying gladiator that may be dead... There is also an orator there indicating in his speech that, indeed, the gladiators were just killing each other a moment ago. At least this is how it reads in Polish translation.

Answer (score 11):

Not likely. We don't see the villain get killed, it's merely implied that he *might* be.

According to the [Sorting Algorithm of Deadness](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SortingAlgorithmOfDeadness) *(warning: TV Tropes is a time sink!)*, that would be rated "Maybe Back Later".

Comment: I would even argue that, while *Maybe Back Later* scenes tend to imply an in-universe assumption that a character is dead, a common out-of-universe assumption in these cases is that he isn't.

Answer (score 8):

> The inference of a deadly conclusion is clear.

I dispute that. Given that in the Asterix universe, people are seen surviving:

- heavy beatings (Romans, pirates, Cacofonix, Goths, Normans, robbers, etc. on numerous occasions),
- being shipwrecked at open sea (the pirates in every other book; note that they include an old and fragile man),
- being crushed by a big rock or menhir (Caligula Minus (twice) in *Asterix the Gaul,* p. 14 and p. 18; Getafix (twice), Psychoanalytix, and Cassius Ceramix in *Asterix and the Big Fight),*
- blatant poison (Cleopatra’s taster in *Asterix and Cleopatra,* p. 24 ff. and Vexatius Sinusitus in *Asterix in Switzerland*),
- an explosion (Getafix several times in *Asterix and the Big Fight* and the pirates in *Asterix in Corsica,* p. 19),
- being literally catapulted (Asterix in *Asterix and Caesar’s Gift,* p. 36),
- a headshot by a catapult (unnamed Belgian in *Asterix in Belgium,* p. 36),
- a fall from considerable height (Codfix in *Asterix and the Great Divide,* p. 39 and Watziznehm and Hoodunnit in *Asterix and the Magic Carpet,* p. 2 and p. 42),
- being bound and gagged in a chest for weeks (Dubbelosix and Surreptitius in 
  *Asterix and the Black Gold,* p. 44),
- a direct lightning strike (Cacofonix in *Asterix and the Secret Weapon,* p. 15), and
- being frozen in a block of ice for days or longer (Macaroon in *Asterix and Picts,* p. 2),

my default assumption would be that Binjwatchflix wakes up on a shore the next day, being somewhat battered up at worst.

*Page numbers refer to the ones in the panels, usually in the bottom right.*